# Setting transition to partial curl programmatically/code

Tags: ios, objective-c

In StoryBoard we can set it visually as below

[image]

How can we do the same thing using `.Xib/nib` file ?

```
[self presentViewController:self.infoController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Above code is just using modal style but how to set transition style to Partial Curl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using this code:

```
    #import "InfoController.h"

   - (IBAction)goToSecond:(id)sender { 
         InfoController *vc = [[InfoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoController" bundle:nil];
         vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
         [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
           //completion code here
         }];
     }
```

Comment: One small suggestion.. always use Camel case for `Class names`.

Comment: @Dilip thanks.....your solution is correct one.Although i know UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl is an enum but how to use it where to use it was a question for me....